# Which R structure should be used to store arithmetic expressions?

Tags: r, structure

I want to find a nice structure to store arithmetic expressions in R. The expression can also have mathematical functions like `sin` , `cos`, etc. Say, I have an expression of the form `(A*B)/(3*D) + cos(E)*F - sin(G)*mod(H)`, I want to find a way to store it so that I can extract the expression later. Think of this as a function call where I can send the list of variables, functions and operators to be used with each variable like `express(functions_1, variables_1, operators, functions_2, variables_2)`. Now these parameters contain the information to be used for creating an expression. An example call would be `express (c(sin, cos), ("A", "C"), c("*", "+", "-"), c(mod, NULL), c("B", "D))`. This should result in the expression `sin(A) * mod(B) + cos(C) - D`. How do I store these kind of expressions?
It would be great if you can suggest a better way of calling this function too.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to evaluate R code later ? If that's the case, quote and eval are the way. Quote allows you to store an expression without evaluating it and eval to evaluate it. Or is it another thing that you want ?

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann I don't want to evaluate rather I need to use write this later into a file which contains a lot of other components. That file will be evaluated in some other language.  So,  I want to get a representation of arithmetic expressions inside a structure as it will help in debugging and I want to extend the scope of these expressions from using just mathematical functions to user defined functions.

Comment: R has no built-in computer algebra and hence doesn't know what an "arithmetic expression" is. It only knows expressions and evaluation of expressions. I think that you seem to have a precise opinion of what object you want, what functions you allow inside, etc. Therefore maybe defining by yourself your own S4 class is what you search for ?

Comment: In S4, you can do any validity checks that you want

Comment: I was thinking of using either S4 class, R6 class or a matrix. The issues with using matrix are that if I use row names, column names as variables and the cell values as the operators, I can get multiple expressions involving two variables but I couldn't figure out how to generate long expressions using matrix. I am still exploring other two options i.e S4 and R6. I just wanted to get basic demonstrations of how other people think of doing it.

Comment: Take a look at how the grid package handles the `unit`; it literally stores an athrimetic expression for adding different sized elements to display.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it solve your request, but here is somewhat that could help you :

```r
setClass(
  Class          = "MyExpr",
  contains = "expression"
)
setValidity("MyExpr",
            method = function(object) {
              if (length(object) > 1) return("Only one line of code !!!")
              if ("diff" %in% all.names(object[[1]])) return("I don't want any difference")
              if ("a" %in% all.vars(object[[1]])) return("Variable a ???? It is forbidden !!!")
            })
MyExpr <- function(x) new("MyExpr",parse(text=x))
```

MyExpr is a S4 class, that contains an expression that with some to-be-defined validity.

```r
MyExpr("1+1")

  An object of class "MyExpr"
    expression(1 + 1)

MyExpr("1+diff(1:10)")

  Error in validObject(.Object) : 
    invalid class “MyExpr” object: I dont want any difference

MyExpr("1+a")

  Error in validObject(.Object) : 
    invalid class “MyExpr” object: Variable a ???? It is forbidden !!!

MyExpr("sin(1+h)")

  An object of class "MyExpr"
    expression(sin(1 + h))
```

Then, you can retrieve into characters the tree of the expression, as it is submitted to R, with something like

```r
getTree_rec <-  function(x) {
  lapply(as.list(x),function(z) if (is.call(z)) getTree_rec(z) else as.character(z))
}

setGeneric("getTree", def = function(object) standardGeneric("getTree"))
setMethod(f="getTree",
          signature="MyExpr",
          definition = function(object) getTree_rec(object[[1]]))
getTree(MyExpr("sin(1+h)"))
[[1]]
[1] "sin"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "+"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "1"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "h"
```

Note : you could also have put `z` instead of `as.character(z)`. I put as.character(z) only because you told you wanted to write something in a file, for another language to read.

Comment: Definitely gives an insight to what I want to achieve. I won't send the whole expression as a string. I will have to modify `MyExpr` function and see if I can get it done.